# stack smashing detected and and with the flag -Wall gives me the Warning -Wchar-subscripts

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, stack-smash

it s my first program ever i dont know how to solve this problems i'm searching for tutorials but i don't totally understand what i am doing wrong.

```
void railFenceCipher(char *stringa){
 
  char railFence[3][56];
  char output[56];
  char k;

  for (char i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (char j = 0; j < 56; j++) {
      railFence[i][j] = ' ';
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < 56; j += 4) {
      railFence[i][j] = stringa[k++];
    }
  }

  k = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 56; j++) {
      if (railFence[j][i] != ' ') {
        output[k++] = railFence[j][i];
      }
    }
  }

  output[k] = '\0';
  printf("Encrypted message: %s\n", output);

}
```

this should be a function that take a string from the main function and encrypt it with the rail fence cipher. but i don't know how to solve the errors stack smashing detected and the warning -Wchar-subscripts

Comment: You use `k` in your second loop nest without initializing it first.

Comment: With `-Wchar-subscripts`, you will get warnings for any use of a variable of type `char` as an array subscript.  To avoid such warnings, use a different type. `int` would be conventional if you're sure it's wide enough for your needs, and there's usually no advantage to using a narrower type.

Comment: i have converted the varibles in int to avoid the warning and the stack smashing error doesn t show anymore but now the program doesn t print out anything

Comment: Welcome, please don't correct the posted code: it makes nonsense of the responses. Just correct your own code, and this site isn't a rolling tutorial.

Comment: `stringa[k++];` you never check if `stringa` is long enough.

Comment: Your algorithm looks a bit odd. It seems you are distributing characters in wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is a major problem:

```
char railFence[3][56];

// ...

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 56; j++) {
    if (railFence[j][i] != ' ') {
      output[k++] = railFence[j][i];
    }
  }
}
```

The indexes `i` and `j` are switched in these loops.